# Using converted NSNumber to NSString returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

I have built one 'deep' NSMutableDictionary that contains parsed XML data along with other relevant information that I can pass from one view controller to another. The NSMutableDictionary contains mostly NSStrings but also another NSMutableDictionary more NSStrings and finally followed even deeper with an NSMutableArray of custom objects (it's for a calendar).

Now, because it is a calendar, there are obviously dates involved. The XML data that I receive and parse using NSXMLParser returns strings, so it was on me to convert the day's date to usable numbers. The date in XML comes in with the following format: "MM.DD" I created the following method to do so:

```
- (void)createDateCodesWithString:(NSString *)string 
{ 
   NSInteger monthCode;
   NSInteger dayCode;
   ....
   NSArray *dates = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
   monthCode = [[dates objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
   dayCode = [[dates objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
   ....
   shortDay = [NSNumber numberWithInt:dayCode];
}
```

'shortDay' is a NSNumber* and an ivar and set as a property (nonatomic, retain) for the custom object that I have created. When I run NSLog commands in the console, it appears that 'shortDay' and other data has been stored successfully in the deep NSMutableDictionary. I run in to problems, however, when I try to access the data again. When I access a NSString* stored ivar, things work OK, but when I attempt to access the NSNumber* I am given the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS with either code 1 or code 2. This is how I try to call upon the NSNumber*

```
   NSNumber *number = day.shortDay;
   return [number stringValue];
```

Might the problem be because the NSArray *dates strips the string into month and day strings and the day string, being two characters long, may contain a '0' before, say, a '6' if the day is the 6th of the month? Any advice?

I am happy to post more code if needed.

Comment: Check the NSNumber class reference how to create such an object. Assigning an integer will not work. Didn't you get any warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the memory for `shortDay` is being cleaned up before the next time you try to access it. When assigning it, try this instead:

```
shortDay = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:dayCode] retain];
```

to increase the reference count (AKA take ownership of the object) to avoid the memory being deallocated too early.

If this resolves the problem, you will then need to call `[shortDay release]` in the `dealloc` method of your class, such that the memory for it will be properly deallocated at the right time.

Comment: I am using A.R.C. included in XCode5 so it does all of that for me (mistake?) The retainCount is at 3 when I attempt to access it.

Comment: I take it back, it worked. Thanks! Might you know why the NSNumber is cleaned up early and the NSString is not? Further, because I use A.R.C., will I still need to release shortDay and others?

Comment: You should not use release and retain in ARC enabled projects. I think it will not even compile anyway.

Comment: I took the advice and added retain, it does compile, and with no warnings either. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You probably are not actually using ARC because use of `retain`, `release`, etc. should cause compilation errors.

Comment: If it compiles with a `retain`, then you aren't using ARC.   Don't call `retainCount`, it is useless.  The best fix is to go under the Edit->Refactor menu and "convert to ARC..."

Comment: of course, my mistake. It is using ARC now, and it works. Thanks!